# Trying to pip install django

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python.  I just installed the `get-pip.py` as [instructed in this guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

Now, I am trying to run

```
 pip install Django==1.11.3
```

I get a message that reads

> `pip is not an internal or external command`

All I did was type that into the command prompt.  I though that's how you install a Python library.  What did I do wrong?  I'm running Python 3.6 on on Windows 7.

I followed the instructions here:
My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >

Then under system variables I create a new Variable called PythonPath. In this variable I have C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\other-folders-on-the-path

[image]

This is all I get now.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: Python 3.6 should already have `pip`

Comment: Is the python exe in your system path?

Comment: so actually what you need is: "how to *run* pip"

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type pip and tell us what the output is in an edit to your question, you should have `pip` installed but if you don't that will tell us

Comment: @Professor_Joykill it says in the question.

Comment: You say you downloaded `get-pip.py` but have you run it as documented in the link you offered.

Comment: I just updated my original post.  I don't really know why someone has to go through all these steps to get the simplest thing done.  In R, all libraries and all dependencies are installed automatically.  In C#, VB, and VBA, a user just needs to set a reference to a library by clicking it.  It seems overwhelming for a beginner to go through so many steps.  You would think it would be easy to work with, to get beginners hooked.  I tried to learn Python a couple years ago, and just gave up because it took hours and hours and hours just to do the most basic thing imaginable.